# Remote desktop software to be used within my application

Tags: remote-desktop, logmein

Does anybody know a good, free remote desktop solution to be used within another application, namely, the application I'm developing?

My application displays a list of computers currently available on the local network. I want the user to be able to select one of them, and establish a remote desktop connection to it.

Windows Desktop Connection isn't working for me, since it logs off the user currently working with that particular PC. I need something like [LogMeIn Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/), regarding its direct control of the Mouse and Keyboard, but only working on local network and and not requiring an internet connection, just like Windows Remote Desktop Connection; and of course capable of being invoked through another application.

Thanks all.

EDIT:

I realized there is no need to actually embed the remote desktop software within my application, a simple remote desktop .exe accepting arguments through command-line would be much better. I need something to be fed the name or IP of the remote PC, the Windows account's username and password, and simply connect to the remote PC displaying a single window.

How about that?

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to use one of the various implementations of [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC)?  There are implementations available under various licenses so you should be able to find one to suit your needs.  You could tunnel it over a VPN of some sort if you require more security.

VNC does not have the side effect of logging off any existing users.  However, it does require a client to be installed - as would any solution other than Windows Remote Desktop (which requires only correct permissions).

(As a side note I just discovered there is [an open source VNC client written in C#](http://dnvnccl.sourceforge.net/) - what language is your project written in?)

Also, [Wikipedia has a comprehensive if slightly confusing comparison of remote access software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)

There is an open source .NET application called [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals) that seems to work in a very similar fashion to what you are describing.  It supports RDP and VNC - it might provide a good starting point for your application?

Comment: Have a look at Terminals (http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals), it seems to be very similar to what you are working on

Answer (score 0):

What about [FogCreek CoPilot](https://www.copilot.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a product called SupportSmith SDK that supports what you're looking for. It's a set of ActiveX and .NET components that allow you to easily add remote support to your applications:

[SupportSmith SDK](http://www.componentsource.com/products/supportsmith-sdk/index.html)

Comment: Apparently SupportSmith isn't free.